# Tool that will virtualize BIOS

Tags: virtualization, bios

Is there any application that can virtualize the BIOS?So that you can see the effects of what the changes in the setting of your BIOS. I know that there are many versions of BIOS depending on your hardware. But is it possible to copy it and then virtualize it when you are running your system.
So that you can see if your system can still run after changing the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use a hardware emulator, or a hardware simulator would be a more useful tool. You can investigate some of the virtualisation tools like [BOCHS](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) to see if they offer such functionality. Otherwise, you can look at chip-level simulators like [M5](http://www.m5sim.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to see if they offer such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to virtualize is not the BIOS but rather the motherboard and all of the integrated circuits on it. You probably won't find an emulator with the necessary level of detail outside of the motherboard manufacturers' offices.